# can not have require multiple modules with module.exports in it

Tags: node.js

I have multiple modules and I did:

// module1.js

```
module.exports = function() {
  ...
}
```

// module2.js

```
module.exports = function() {
  ...
}
```

in app.js

```
m1 = require('./module1')
m2 = require('./module2')

m1.method()
m2.method()
```

I get TypeError. Then I ended up exporting methods in both the modules.

is there a way I can export multiple modules other than exporting individual methods explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to pass `require()` an `undefined` variable two times. require() needs to take a string as an argument to determine what module you want to load.

If the other two modules are in the same directory as app.js, try

```
m1 = require('./module1')
m2 = require('./module2')
```

---

**EDIT:**
What you're forgetting to do is

```
m1 = new require('./module1')()
m2 = new require('./module2')()
```

Assuming that you modules look like:

```
module.exports = function() {
  this.method = function(){}
}
```

Personally, instead of a function I would just return an object literal from my module:

```
module.exports = {
  method1: function(){},
  method2: function(){}
}
```

Then I could invoke the methods from the module's export like such:

```
m1 = require('./module1');
m1.method1();
```

Comment: apologies..thats what I did...I just mistyped it in posting question

Comment: ok...I will try that suggestion and update...thanks...so are you saying multiple module.exports are allowed?